# delete button sequence with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm develope a website, in which I will make a delete button with sequence, i mean just one button delete for two input field, it is possible do in jQuery?

Here's my HTML Code:

```
a: <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="username" />
c: <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="password" />
<button type="button" class="delete">
Delete
</button>
```

Here's my jQuery Code:

```
$("input").bind("input", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ( $this.val().length >= parseInt($this.attr("maxlength"),10) )
        $this.next("input").focus();
    },0);
 });

$('#password').on('input', function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    $('#username').focus();
    return false;
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
                        if($('#password').val == '') {
                var $content = $('#username');
            } else if ($('#password').val !== '') {
                var $content = $('#password');
            }
            var html = $content.val();
            $content.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
            if($content.val() == '') {
            $('#username').focus();
            } else if ($content.val() !== '') {
            $content.focus();
            }
            return false;
    });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/557/)

I have tried it myself, but haven't been successful!

Comment: What do you want to do when the "delete" button is clicked?

Comment: @PraneshRavi clear the input filed.

Comment: yes dude, when "delete" button clicked @PraneshRavi

Comment: Are you trying to clear the field at once or delete character by character? Not sure why you'd want to do the latter but that's what it looks like.

Comment: not clear all when "delete" button clicked, but just 1 text delete every button is clicked, you can see on my jsfiddle demo @ToddMark

Comment: delete character by character dude @jeffcarey

Comment: you can see my code `$content.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));` @jeffcarey

Comment: for all, you can see my jsfiddle demo, when i click delete button in #password field, it will be delete character by character, when input field is blank the focus changed to #username field, i clicked delete button with the intention of delete character by character in #username field is not working, that is what I want

Answer (score 2):

The key of this issue is **sequence**. So just detect the length of value of input.

```js
$("input").bind("input", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
   if ( $this.val().length >= parseInt($this.attr("maxlength"),10) )
     $this.next("input").focus();
    },0);
 });
    
$('#password').on('input', function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    $('#username').focus();
    return false;
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
 var username = $('#username');
  var password = $('#password');
  password.val(password.val().substr(0, password.val().length - 1));
  
  if (password.val().length == 0) {
   username.val(username.val().substr(0, username.val().length - 1));
  }
 return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
a: <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="username" />
c: <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="password" />
<button type="button" class="delete">
Delete
</button>
```

Comment: yeah tq, i want password first when delete button is clicked, but is not problem and thanks for helping me.

Comment: @RofiFathurrohman I have changed the order. You can check it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the parentheses in the val checks at the start of your delete function. Change val to val() in each:

```
if($('#password').val() == '') {
    var $content = $('#username');
} else if ($('#password').val() !== '') {
    var $content = $('#password');
}
```